# Chrome Refreshes On Orientation Change

Tags: chrome-for-android, orientation

I recently wiped my phone and reinstalled the same custom, rooted, stock ROM.

Since then, when I rotate the phone, Chrome rotates the display (as expected) but then refreshes the page.  The loading bar goes across, a YouTube video will stop playing, and depending on the page the scroll position is lost.

Before, the display would simply rotate in place without issue.

I have never seen this behavior before and I cannot find any relevant setting to change it, including in chrome://flags.

What is causing Chrome to refresh when I change the screen orientation?

Comment: Try clearing data of chrome (settings>apps>chrome>storage>manage storage>clear data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disabled the DPI override for Chrome in the App Settings app for Xposed, and the problem went away.

Now I'll search for a different way to adjust Chrome's DPI.

Notes:

- This issue did not occur in Chrome 52, the stock version for this ROM
- Clearing Chrome app data did not fix the issue

In the end, I set the DPI for the entire phone to match the desired DPI for Chrome, via the `ro.sf.lcd_density` setting in the file `build.prop`.  I then changed the DPI of other apps as necessary with Xposed: App Settings.

Comment: Have you found a workaround for this? It breaks my flow while browsing but at the same time, I need the upscaled Chrome UI

Comment: I did. See edited answer

Comment: Wow that's kind of a scorched earth approach I feel. I may have to weigh down the importance of things before committing to something like that as I have a shitton of apps that I don't need to change the scaling for